# Is it possible to merge Lucene.NET indexes

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have a number of Lucene.NET indexes created for archive files.
The indexes are created in an identical manner.
The indexes don't change but each index takes days to complete.
I want single application to query all indexes.

I'm wondering if it is possible to merge these indexes into a single index?

I know that an alternative approach would be to create a search app that queries each index in turn - but that is not my preferred option as it introduces a large maintenance overhead due to reasons I can't explain here.

Comment: 5 second Google search: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes  ->  https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool.html

Answer (score 2):

The index merge tool, as commented on by @DarkFalcon, is also available for .Net, [see here](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Misc/Misc/IndexMergeTool.cs).  Doesn't look like that works.  Looks like an automatic port of Java Lucene 4.5.0, or some such, and won't work with the currently version of Lucene.Net.

However, it's actually pretty simple to merge indexes, through the `IndexWriter` API.  You can use the [`IndexWriter.AddIndexes`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d1d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_index_writer.html#a9b0b1546bb8fee0480823dee19046f45) method.  Just open a writer on the destination index, open readers on each of the indexes to be merged in, chuck them into an array, and call that method.

---

As far as managing multiple indexes, you can search multiple indexes much more effectively by using [MultiReader](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d6/d9d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_multi_reader.html), instead of hand merging the results of separate searches.

---

Here's a version of the IndexMergeTool that should actually work:

```
using System;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

public class IndexMergeTool
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Usage: IndexMergeTool <mergedIndex> <index1> <index2> [index3] ...");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        FSDirectory mergedIndex = FSDirectory.Open(args[0]);

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(mergedIndex, null, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        IndexReader[] indexes = new IndexReader[args.Length - 1];
        for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i - 1] = IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open(args[i]), true);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Merging...");
        writer.AddIndexes(indexes);

        Console.WriteLine("Closing Readers...");
        foreach (IndexReader index in indexes)
        {
            index.Dispose();
        }
        writer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with some minor modifications since I'm using Lucene.net 2.9.2.  I had to use a DirectoryInfo arg for FSDirectory.Open.  Thanks!